# Plot frequency heatmap of positions from set of coordinates

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I have a bunch of data that looks like this:

```
  Track X1        X        Y
1 Point  1 147.8333 258.5000
2 Point  2 148.5000 258.8333
3 Point  3 151.1667 260.8333
4 Point  4 154.5000 264.5000
5 Point  5 158.1667 266.5000
6 Point  6 161.5000 269.5000
```

I want to plot a [heatmap](/questions/tagged/heatmap) of this, so a nice looking graph labelled `x` and `y` for the position coordinates, with a `gradient color fill` indicating the frequency that a particular point showed up, with a scale indicator showing what the colors mean. I'm looking for a simple `gradient fill` with a single color low and high.

I've been at this for a while but I think the first step should be to construct another data-set with the positions and a new column showing the frequencies? But I'm not 100% sure how to structure this.

So far my attempts look similar to:

```
ggplot(data=all_data, aes(x=X, y=Y)) + geom_tile(aes(fill=all_data$X)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="green", high="blue") + coord_equal()
```

Comment: Try this: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bin2d.html

Comment: For hexagonal binning instead: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_hex.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Jon Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6851825/jon-spring) suggested, the following code shows up a graph like this:

```
all_data <- read.table(text = "
Track X1        X        Y
1 Point  1 147.8333 258.5000
2 Point  2 148.5000 258.8333
3 Point  3 151.1667 260.8333
4 Point  4 154.5000 264.5000
5 Point  5 158.1667 266.5000
6 Point  6 161.5000 269.5000
", header = T, row.names = NULL)

ggplot(data=all_data, aes(x=X, y=Y)) + geom_bin2d()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'd add that to add a nice gradient you could do something like: `geom_hex(colour="white") + scale_fill_gradient2(high="darkred")`.